# Call function for Rails colleciton_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, collection-select

I need to better manipulate a strong for a collection_select. I only see how to call a function on  the object, but I need to do some more manipulation that the object won't know about. Is there a way to do this?

Currently:

```
lif.collection_select(:tier_id, @lif_plan.tiers, :id, :tiername)
```

I tried this and it didn't work (thinking it would pass the tier object in)

```
lif.collection_select(:tier_id, @lif_plan.tiers, :id, {|tier| "#{tier.tiername} - #{@member.tierrate(year_of_rate)} "} )
```

My challenge is that the tier will not know what it should be doing without additional information so I can't just make a function in there to return. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, remember that collection_select is expecting a Proc/Method there. So it will try to send a :call message to it.

Change it to the following and try again:

```
lif.collection_select(:tier_id, @lif_plan.tiers, :id, Proc.new {|tier| "#{tier.tiername} - #{@member.tierrate(year_of_rate)} "} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up switching to the select command for it but will use this going forward! lif.select(:tier_id, @lif_plan_tiers.map {|tier| ["#{tier.tiername} - #{@member.tierrate(year_of_rate)} ", tier.id]})